# OpenVPN doesn't open tap0

Tags: kali-linux, openvpn, network-interface

I'm connecting to an `openvpn` server using a `.ovpn` config file. I authenticate just fine using keys and cert, but `openvpn` seems to fail to open `tap0`:

```
Wed Oct 19 14:04:47 2016 TUN/TAP device tap0 opened
Wed Oct 19 14:04:47 2016 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Oct 19 14:04:47 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
Wed Oct 19 14:04:47 2016 write to TUN/TAP : Input/output error (code=5)
Wed Oct 19 14:04:47 2016 write to TUN/TAP : Input/output error (code=5)
```

Although `openvpn` claims `tap0 opened`, `ifconfig` clearly only shows `eth0` and `lo`. There is no `tap0` interface, which explains the Input/output errors in the log above. Naturally, the VPN tunnel is not working.

Google was of no help. Does anyone have any clue what could be causing this?

I'm using the latest kali, fully updated.

Comment: what are the ip addresses?

Comment: Is the other end also configured for bridging rather than routing?

Comment: @IporSircer Would that have any influence? It's not a local IP. A few other guys I know are logging in fine with the same config file, that's why I think it's probably my system.

Comment: @roaima I believe so, other people are logging in with the same config file, so I think the problem is on my end.